# replace fix position in muti line perl variable

Tags: perl, variables, replace, line

A perl variable is having multiple line value assigned to it.

```
2100010000   
2200010000  
2300010000  
3100010001  
3200010001
```

I want to replace position 3 to 6 at each line with another value like 0004.

```
2100040000  
2200040000  
2300040000  
3100040001  
3200040001
```

I don't want to loop through each line in perl variable.

Answer (score 3):

You can perform a regular expression replacement on a multi-line string by using the `m` flag.  To perform all such replacements, use the `g` flag.  In the multi-line context, the `^` character will match the beginning of each line of the multi-line string.

`$numbers =~ s|^(\d{2})(\d{4})|$1$replacement|mg;`

means find all matches of lines starting with 2-digits followed by 4-digits and 
replace that with the first 2-digits which are captured in `$1` followed by the string inside variable `$replacement`.

[perldoc perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) gives a gentle introduction to the topic.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $numbers = <<EONUMBERS;
2100010000
2200010000
2300010000
3100010001
3200010001
EONUMBERS

my $replacement = '0004';

print "before:\n$numbers";
$numbers =~ s|^(\d{2})(\d{4})|$1$replacement|mg;
print "after:\n$numbers";
```

**output**

```
before:
2100010000
2200010000
2300010000
3100010001
3200010001
after:
2100040000
2200040000
2300040000
3100040001
3200040001
```